# how to write an xml file in flash( with dotnet frame work)

Tags: .net, flash

i am trying    to  develop an  flash  application.

where  they have  designed the entire  front end  by flash. now i need  to  doing the   functionality part  like  taking the data  from flash  and  save in   database(sqlserver  r  mysql)  using  ( asp.net 3.5  frame work)
   .
  now  as  flash is  able  to read  xml file  there is no issue in it.

but  how  to  write an  xml file  from  flash  and  send  to   dot net frame  work.
 like in the page  we have   3  textbox  where an user  enter the  values. now i need    take  those value    and put in an xml  format  and  from xml  format  give the data   to  .net framework  extract the req  values  from xml  and  save in data base  which will be  done in c#  coding

is  this  logic  going to work.   is there any  other  solution   to  solve the  promblem

thank  you

Answer (score 2):

You can create xml in flash using the e4x syntax.

```
var xml:XML = <root/>;
var child:XML;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  child = <text/>;
  child.@id = i + 1;
  child.appendChild(textFields[i].text);
  xml.appendChild(child);
}
//always use toXMLString (and not toString) on xml objects
//this is because toString returns empty string for an xml object 
//without any children (like <root id="3"/>)
trace(xml.toXMLString());

//send it using url loader
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("serverurl.asp");
req.data = xml.toXMLString();
urlLoader.load(req);
```

BTW, you need not use xml for passing data from flash to server. You can pass it as an html query string.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
//you can use dot syntax and/or [] syntax to add data.
data.total = 3;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  data["text" + (i + 1)] = textFields[i].text;
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("serverurl.asp");
req.data = data;
//it sends "total=3&text1=firsttext&text2=secondtext&text3=thirdText"
urlLoader.load(req);
```